# Client server program and mode_t

Tags: c, linux, client-server, mode

I need to send a variable of type mode_t through a socket. How do i do it? I mean I could convert it to a string using snprintf()..but is it ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transmit `mode_t` safely you must convert it to some alternate form. There is no reason to believe the two hosts communicating will use the same flag definitions for `mode_t`, so printing it as an integer is not even sufficient; you need to iterate over all the mode flags and check each one.

Answer (score 1):

`mode_t` is an integer.

Indeed, having textual protocols on sockets is practically useful (easier to debug and to evolve).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's ok to use strings. But you can check functions like `htobe32` and `be32toh` from the header `<endian.h>` if you want to send it as integers.

Comment: These are ugly nonstandard names for the functions `htonl` and `ntohl`... Also, who says `mode_t` has to fit in 32 bits, or even that it has the same bit patterns on both ends of the socket?

Comment: @R.. Yes, but it have 64-bit variants, even if it's not needed in this case.